# PHP preg_match: exclude whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-negation

I'm working on some code block that validates a config file containing PHP variable. I want to detect variables left empty using preg_match.

If the file contains the following lines:

```
$db_host = "blablah";
  $db_host   ='blablah';
$db_host='';
    $db_host=" ";
  $db_host="";
```

I'd like to match only lines 3-4-5, lines 1 and 2 being valid (no empty value). The following preg_match works well but matches all lines, not handling the whitespaces or empty values; how could I match only empty/whitespaced values?

```
preg_match( '#\$db_host(\ +)?\=(\ +)?(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\");#i', $string );
```

Note: I'd rather not included the files to validate to check their validity. There might be a lot of them and I can't assume I'll always have control on their content. I'd rather not include unknown, third party code into my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\$db_host\s*=\s*(["\'])\s*\1\s*;~';
```

`\s*` means "any white character zero or more times". White characters are spaces, tabs, carriage returns and newlines, but if you want, you can replace `\s` by `\h` that matches only horizontal white characters (i.e. tabs and spaces).

I put the type of quote in a capturing group with `(["\'])` and then I use a backreference to this group with `\1` (1 because it is the first capturing group of the pattern).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't say I understand the Regex, but it does match every test I could find. Thanks again!

Comment: @Askelon: I will add explanations later.

Answer (score 3):

How should your regex check something like this?:

```
$a = '';
$b = $a;
$c = preg_replace('/.*/', $a);
```

You should use PHP to check the variables and not a regex:

```
include 'config.php';

foreach(array(
    'db_host', 'db_pass', ...
) as $varname) {
    $value = trim($$varname);
    if(empty($value)) {
        die($varname . ' must not be empty');
    }
}
```

Also you should use `trim()` to avoid variables containing just whitespace content. (thanks @SamuelCook)

Comment: I should have said I don't really want to use include on this, I edited my question. There might be a lot of files to check and I don't really have any real control on what their full content is. It seemed more secure to me to get the content as text and preg_match it to extract what I know I should find in them, rather than blindly include them along with potential unfriendly code.

Comment: If there is potentially unfriendly code in that files, security is already badly broken. No one should be able to place insecure code into your config files. If you want to avoid this in general then use a different format like ini, xml or json to store config values.

Comment: Can't disagree with that, previous client's dev truly mess up here. But anyway, I have to handle these files… Isn't there a way to make the Regex I posted handle whitespaces?

Comment: Using preg_match will be even more unreliable. If a function, constant or variable is used in the files to set a value it will getting impossible to check if a value is empty or not using a regex. It depends on what you want to do. Just for having a look manually a regex might fit, but if it should an automated, stable, unbreakable solution a regex won't work.

Comment: You might start an sub process for including the config files to avoid possible namespace pollution of your application. I would do so.

Comment: I would too had I the liberty to do it, but I don't… Anyway there are a battery of tests after that to check the results. The variables I'm getting this way are not supposed to change anywhere after being declared, so that should be a problem. I'll go with the regex Casimir et Hippolyte provided below and ask for the possibility of handling the files otherwise in the futur. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem. if you can change it once I would use ini, xml or json files. I prefer xml. You may write a xml schema to validate the config. That's the super deluxe solution: When properly done, even the IDE used to edit config files will complain about empty fields :)

Answer (score 2):

Why use preg_match when you can use `trim()` & `empty()` to check if it's empty or not.

Take the following examples:

```
<?php
$str[0] = ' ';
$str[1] = "\t";
$str[2] = "\r\n";

foreach($str as $k=>$val){
    $val = trim($val);
    if(empty($val)){
        echo $k.' is empty<br>';
    }
}
```

They will all return empty.

Comment: +1 for the `trim()` usage. Really makes sense here! Have adapted that to my answer, thx

Comment: Actually I don't see how I could use trim() and empty() here: I'm trying to parse third party config files and want to extract specific lines from them, if they match a valid PHP var definition.